# Set Data Annotation MaxLength w/ Variable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to set the `[MaxLength()]` data annotation in my EF Core 7 entity with a variable. Here's my code.

```
    public static class Constants
    {
        public static byte IdentifierMaxLength { get { return 46; } }
        public static byte NameMaxLength { get { return 64; } }
        public static ushort DescriptionMaxLength { get { return 1024; } }
        public static ushort UsageMaxLength { get { return 1024; } }
    }

    public class TagEntity
    {
        private byte _maxIdentifierLength;

        public Tag()
        {
            _maxIdentifierLength = Constants.IdentifierMaxLength;
        }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(_maxIdentifierLength)]
        public string Identifier { get; set; }
    }
    
    // Or better yet:
    [MaxLength(Constants.IdentifierMaxLength)]
```

I get this error instead:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Tag._maxIdentifierLength'

Is this possible? If not, is there another way to go about this so I don't have to change these lengths in multiple places if they ever need to change?

Comment: Consider changing the items in `Constants` to actually be constants, then you can use them in attributes.

Comment: As @gunr2171 said, change the constants to be `const` instead. Also the signature for the MaxLengthAttribute is `int`. Instead of using byte and ushort, use int instead.

Comment: Doing this ```public const byte IdentifierMaxLength { get { return 46; } }``` results in error. Are you saying to replace the properties with say ``` public const IdentifierMaxLength = 46;``` ?

Comment: @gunr2171 If you write this as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @Hayden If I could up-vote comments I would up-vote yours. I'll change to int's. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values provided to Attributes must be known at compile time. Constants are a good way of providing that guarantee.

Change your `Constants` class to have actual constants. In addition, you'll need/want to change the type to `int` to match the parameter for the attribute.

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const int IdentifierMaxLength = 46;
}
```

Now you can do

```
[MaxLength(Constants.IdentifierMaxLength)]
```